# Encapsulating matplotlib plot update in a class, when using dispatcher package

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, dispatch

I am trying to encapsulate a matplotlib plot update inside a class. The idea being that a signal (i.e. event) is dispatched, and the listening instance should update a plot. I'm currently using [dispatcher](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dispatcher), but I've also tried with [PyDispatcher](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDispatcher) with the same result.

Here's a simplified code of what I want to do, including what works and what doesn't:

```
from time import sleep
from random import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import dispatch

plt.ion()

# define signal to be dispatched
plot_update = dispatch.Signal(providing_args=["y"])

# non-encapsulated update (this works alright)
fig = plt.figure('This Works')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax.plot([1], [0], 'ko')
ax.axis((0, 2, 0, 1))

def update_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    line1.set_ydata(kwargs['y'])
    fig.canvas.draw()

plot_update.connect(update_callback)



# class to encapsulate plot update behavior
class DynamicPlot(object):
    def __init__(self, fid_name):
        self.fig = plt.figure(fid_name)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line1, = self.ax.plot([1], [0], 'ko')
        self.ax.axis((0, 2, 0, 1))
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

        def _update_callback(sender, **kwargs):
            self.line1.set_ydata(kwargs['y'])
            self.fig.canvas.draw()

        # I'd expect this to connect _update_callback to be triggered 
        # when the `plot_update` signal is dispatched, but that's not 
        # happening
        plot_update.connect(_update_callback)

    # Calling this method, will update the plot, but this 
    # is not what I need (is just here for testing)
    def update(self, y):
        self.line1.set_ydata(y)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

# test code
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # this one should update by listening to events (signal) 
    d1 = DynamicPlot("This Won't Work")

    # this instance is here just for testing, to make sure 
    # the class can update a plot via a different mechanism
    d2 = DynamicPlot("This Will Work Too")

    # mocked signal dispatcher
    while(True):
        plot_update.send(sender=None, y=[random()])
        d2.update([random()])
        sleep(0.1)
```

The non-encapsulated version works as expected. When I use the class, I can call the update method and it does what it should. But what I really need is to be able to update the plot without explicitly calling the update method (to avoid undesired coupling). Hence the dispatch package.

I've tested and `_update_callback` is being called. I know the event is being dispatched (otherwise, the non-encapsulated version wouldn't work), so the only explanation I can think of is that `plot_update.connect(_update_callback)` is not doing what it is supposed to, but I have no clue on why?

Any ideas on why this doesn't work as expected? Better yet, any ideas on how to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research, I realized the problem was that the `connect()` method of `dispatcher.Signal` attempts to use **weak references** to the callback function by default. The solution to my problem is to pass `weak=false` to `connect()`. Here's what I'm saying in code (example from the question, but removed test and non-encapsulated code):

```
from time import sleep
from random import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import dispatch


plot_update = dispatch.Signal(providing_args=["y"])

plt.ion()

class DynamicPlot(object):
    def __init__(self, fid_name):
        self.fig = plt.figure(fid_name)
        plt.clf()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line1, = self.ax.plot([1], [0], 'ko')
        self.ax.axis((0, 2, 0, 1))
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        plt.show()

        def _update_callback(sender, **kwargs):
            self.line1.set_ydata(kwargs['y'])
            self.fig.canvas.draw()

        plot_update.connect(_update_callback, weak=False)
        # plot_update.connect(tmp(self))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    d1 = DynamicPlot("Not it Works!")

    while(True):
        plot_update.send_robust(sender=None, y=[random()])
        sleep(0.1)
```

Hope this helps someone else!